# A nested INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, or MERGE statement must have an OUTPUT clause in UPDATE

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I'm trying to update some values based on every Id in the list. The logic I have seems to be what I want.

I want to populate a temporary table of Ids. Then for every ID I want to apply this query and output the deleted date and the ID into a new table I've created.

I keep getting the error:

`Msg 10716, Level 15, State 1, Line 25
A nested INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, or MERGE statement must have an OUTPUT clause.`

What does this mean? I thought I am OUTPUTTING into the new table I've created.

```
USE datatemp

GO


DECLARE @idlist TABLE (id INT)
INSERT INTO @idlist (id) VALUES (3009099)

DECLARE @EndDate DATETIME
SET @EndDate = '2099-12-12'

IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'TEMP_TABLE')
BEGIN
    CREATE TABLE  [TEMP_TABLE] (     
        [id] INT,
        [thedatetoend] DATETIME); 
END

BEGIN TRY
    SELECT  *
    FROM @idlist AS idlist
        OUTER APPLY(
                    UPDATE [custprofile]
                    SET thedatetoend = @EndDate
                    OUTPUT idlist.id, DELETED.thedatetoend
                        INTO [TEMP_TABLE]
                    FROM [custprofile] as bc
                    INNER JOIN [custinformation] as cc
                    ON cc.custengageid = bc.custengageid
                    WHERE cc.id = idlist.id
                                    AND bc.modifierid = 2
                                    AND bc.thedatetoend > GETDATE()
                                    AND cc.type = 1) o
```

Comment: I think that's just a standard error message that comes up when someone incorrectly tries to do an update/insert/merge/delete in a select statement (which you cannot do). You should rework the way your update statement is structured so that it's something like `update blah set blah = blah from table1 as a join table2 as b where id in (select id from @idlist) and blah = blah;` and if you need to output the updated/deleted values you can do that within your update statement.

Comment: you output into `[TEMP_TABLE]` but what makes you think that's going to 'appear' outside - it's not. You need a `SELECT * FROM [TEMP_TABLE]` to do that. It also looks like you're missing some code - you have no `END TRY`. Lastly I don't see why `OUTER APPLY` is necessary. Maybe you just want `CROSS JOIN`

Answer (score 1):

I think you may have more success by using a CTE and avoiding the outer apply approach you are currently using. Updates made to the CTE cascade to the source table. It might look something like the following but as some columns don't reference the table aliases don't expect this to work "as is" (i.e. I'm not sure if you are outputting ccid or bcid and I don't know which table thedatetoend belongs to.)

```
WITH
      CTE AS (
                  SELECT
                        cc.id AS ccid, bcid AS bcid, thedatetoend
                  FROM [custprofile] AS bc
                  INNER JOIN [custinformation] AS cc ON cc.custengageid = bc.custengageid
                  INNER JOIN @idlist AS idlist ON cc.id = idlist.id
                  WHERE bc.modifierid = 2
                  AND bc.thedatetoend > GETDATE()
                  AND cc.type = 1
            )
UPDATE CTE
SET thedatetoend = @EndDate
OUTPUT ccid, DELETED.thedatetoend
INTO [TEMP_TABLE]
```